# Understanding the Bennett Acceptance Ratio (BAR) method

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, physical-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

The Bennett acceptance ratio method (BAR) is a method for computing free energy differences. See also

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bennett_acceptance_ratio)
- [Alchemistry.org](http://www.alchemistry.org/wiki/Bennett_Acceptance_Ratio)
- [Original publication](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999176900784)

I have problems understand the very beginning of the derivation in the original publication:

> ...weighting function. Let $W(q_1,...,q_N)$ be an everywhere-finite function of the coordinates. It then follows easily that $$\frac{Q_0}{Q_1}=\frac{Q_0\int W \exp(-U_0-U_1)dq^N}{Q_1\int W \exp(-U_1-U_0)dq^N}{Q_1}=\frac{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle_1}{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle_0} \tag{6}$$ IIb. *Optimized Acceptance Ratio Estimator--Large Sample Regime*
>
> Optimization of the free energy estimate is the most easily carried out in the limit of large samples sizes. Let the available data consist of $n_0$ statistically independent configurations from the $U_0$ ensemble and $n_1$ from the $U_1$ ensemble, and let this data be used in Eq. (6) to obtain a finite sample estimate of the reduced free energy difference $\Delta A=A_1-A_0=\ln(Q_0/Q_1)$. For sufficiently large sample sizes, the error of this estimate will be nearly Gaussian, and its expected square will be $$\text{Expectation of } (\Delta A_{est}-\Delta A)^2 \approx \frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_1)\rangle_0}{n_0[\langle W \exp(-U_1) \rangle_0]^2}+\frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_0)\rangle_1}{n_1[\langle W \exp(-U_0) \rangle_1]^2}-\frac{1}{n_0}-\frac{1}{n_1}=\frac{\int ((Q_0/n_0)\exp(-U_1)+(Q_1/n_1)\exp(-U_0))W^2\exp(-U_0-U_1)dq^N}{[\int\exp(-U_0-U_1)dq^N]^2}-(1/n_0)-(1/n_1)$$

Can someone explain to my how this formula is derived?
E.g. why are there no logarithms? (energy differences in terms of partition functions involve the natural logarithm ln, as written in the text above). Or why are there no sums in the formula? (The estimated value of the free energy difference should be a finite sum of weighted values).

Comment: sorry not an answer, but if you found an answer, can you share it here?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation 1 shows what Bennet wrote on his paper as equation 7. From now on, I will call this equation 1.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{Expectation of} \ (\Delta A_{est} -\Delta A)^2\\
&\approx \frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_1)\rangle _0}{n_0[\langle W\exp(-U_1)\rangle _0]^2}+\frac{\langle W^2\exp(-2U_0)\rangle _1}{n_1[\langle W\exp(-U_0)\rangle _1]^2}-\frac{1}{n_0}-\frac{1}{n_1}\\
&=\frac{\int((Q_0/n_0)\exp(-U_1)+(Q_1/n_1)\exp(-U_0))W^2\exp(-U_0-U_1)dq^N}{[\int W\exp(-U_0-U_1)dq^N]^2}\\
&\ \ \ \ -(1/n_0)-(1/n_1)
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
It is the first approximation($\approx$) step where many including myself are confused. First of all recall that Bennett, earlier in the paper have shown the following equality,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{Q_0}{Q_1} = \frac{Q_0\int W \exp(-U_0-U_1)dq^N}{Q_1\int W \exp(-U_1-U_0)dq^N} = \frac{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1}{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0},
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
which is numbered equation 6 in the paper. Recall that $\langle  \rangle _1$ indicates that the values in the bracket are average over configuration at state 1 whereas  $\langle  \rangle _0$ indicates that the values in the bracket are average over configuration at state 0.The result here is exact, meaning that no approximation is used. Using this relation and the fact that free energy difference can be written in the following form, $\Delta A = A_1-A_0=\ln(Q_0/Q_1)$, where $\beta(\frac{1}{k_b T})$ is included in $A_1$ and $A_0$, the very first line of the equation 1 can be written as following.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{Expectation of} (\Delta A_{est} -\Delta A)^2\\
&= \langle (\Delta A_{est} -\Delta A)^2\rangle \\
&= \langle (\ln\frac{Q_{0,est}}{Q_{1,est}}-\ln\frac{Q_0}{Q_1})^2\rangle \\
&= \langle (\ln\frac{\frac{1}{n_1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))}{\frac{1}{n_0}\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W \exp(-U_1(r_{0,i}))}-\ln\frac{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1}{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0})^2\rangle 
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
$Q_{0,est}$, and $Q_{1,est}$ indicate estimated $Q_0$ and $Q_1$ from simulation data, $n_0$ and $n_1$ are number of samples obtain at each state, 0 and 1, $r_{0,i}$ is the $i$th point obtained from simulation at state 0, and $r_{1,j}$ is the $j$th point obtained from simulation at state 1. Now, rearrange the final line in equation 3.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&= \langle (\ln\frac{\frac{1}{n_1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))}{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1}-\ln\frac{\frac{1}{n_0}\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W \exp(-U_1(r_{0,i}))}{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0})^2\rangle 
\end{aligned}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}
At large sampling regime, the following approximations can be made.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\frac{1}{n_1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))}{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1} \approx 1\\
\frac{\frac{1}{n_0}\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W \exp(-U_1(r_{0,i}))}{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0} \approx 1\\
\end{aligned}
\tag{5}
\end{equation}
Also, when $x \approx 1, \ln(x) \approx x-1$ and as a result, equation 4 can be rewritten as following.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&= \langle (\frac{\frac{1}{n_1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))}{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1}-\frac{\frac{1}{n_0}\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W \exp(-U_1(r_{0,i}))}{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0})^2\rangle \\
&=\langle \frac{(\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j})))^2}{n_1^2\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2}+\frac{(\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W \exp(-U_1(r_{0,i})))^2}{n_0^2\langle W \exp(-U_1\rangle _0^2}\\
&\ \ \ \ -2\frac{\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W \exp(-U_1(r_{0,i}))}{n_0 n_1 \langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0}\rangle \\
&=\langle \frac{\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W^2 \exp(-2U_0(r_{1,j}))}{n_1^2\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2}\rangle +\langle \frac{\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j\neq j'}WW'\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j'}))}{n_1^2\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2}\rangle \\
&+\langle \frac{\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W^2 \exp(-2U_1(r_{0,i}))}{n_0^2\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0^2}\rangle +\langle \frac{\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i\neq i'}WW'\exp(-U_1(r_{0,i}))\exp(-U_1(r_{0,i'}))}{n_0^2\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0^2}\rangle \\
&-2\langle \frac{\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}W \exp (-U_0(r_{1,j}))\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}W \exp(-U_1(r_{0,i}))}{n_0n_1\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0}\rangle ,
\end{aligned}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}
where $W'$ is the value of function $W$ with configuration $r(1,j')$ or $r(0,i')$.
Now, let's take a closer look at the numerator on the second term of the last line on equation 6 which is,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\langle \sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j\neq j'}WW'\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j'}))\rangle \\
&=\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j\neq j'}\langle WW'\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j'}))\rangle 
\end{aligned}
\tag{7}
\end{equation}
The second summation is over $j'$ where $j'$ is not equal to $j$. With this in mind, it is safe to assume that the function that depends on $j$, $W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))$, is uncorrelated with the function that depends on $j'$, $W' \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j'}))$. If, for instance, function $f$ and $g$ are uncorrelated, average of $f$ multiplied with $g$, $\langle f g\rangle $, are equal to multiple of average $f$ and average $g$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle  f g \rangle  = \langle  f \rangle  \langle  g \rangle \ \text{if f and g are uncorrelated}
\end{aligned}
\tag{8}
\end{equation}
Then we can rearrange the last line on equation 7,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j\neq j'}\langle WW'\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))\exp(-U_0(r_{1,j'}))\rangle \\
&=\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j\neq j'}\langle W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j}))\rangle \langle W \exp(-U_0(r_{1,j'}))\rangle \\
&=n(n-1)\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2.
\end{aligned}
\tag{9}
\end{equation}
Note that on the last line of equation 9, subscript 1 on the average($\langle  \rangle $) indicates that the average is taken over configurations at state 1 whereas the average on the second line of equation 9 does not have subscript 1. However, it was implied in the equation on the second line of equation 9 that the average is the average over state 1, as configurations taken into account are the ones from state 1($r_{\textbf{1},j}$, $r_{\textbf{1},j'}$). By applying the same analogy to the  4th and 5th term on the last line of equation 6, and taking the summation signs out from the bracket($\langle  \rangle $)we get,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&=\sum\limits^{n_1}_{j=1}\frac{1}{n_1^2}\frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_0(r_{1,j}))\rangle }{\langle W \exp -U_0\rangle _1^2} + \frac{n_1(n_1-1)}{n_1^2}\frac{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2}{\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2}\\
&+\sum\limits^{n_0}_{i=1}\frac{1}{n_0^2}\frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_1(r_{0,i}))\rangle }{\langle W \exp -U_1\rangle _0^2} + \frac{n_0(n_0-1)}{n_0^2}\frac{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0^2}{\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0^2}\\
&+2\frac{n_0n_1}{n_0n_1}\frac{\langle W \exp -U_0\rangle _1\langle W \exp -U_1\rangle _0}{\langle W \exp -U_0\rangle _1\langle W \exp -U_1\rangle _0}
\end{aligned}
\tag{10}
\end{equation}
After some basic  algebra, we get,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&=\frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_0(r_{1,j}))\rangle }{n_1\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2}+\frac{n_1-1}{n_1}+\frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_1(r_{0,i}))\rangle }{n_0\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0^2}+\frac{n_0-1}{n_0}-2\\
&=\frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_0)\rangle _1}{n_1\langle W \exp(-U_0)\rangle _1^2}+\frac{\langle W^2 \exp(-2U_1)\rangle _0 }{n_0\langle W \exp(-U_1)\rangle _0^2}-\frac{1}{n_1}-\frac{1}{n_0},
\end{aligned}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}
which is exactly what Bennet wrote on the second line of equation 7 in the paper.

Comment: You should use `\exp` instead of `exp` in your MathJax, as it is an operator and not the product if three variables. Additionally, you can use `\langle` and `\rangle` for your bras & keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, very much appreciate it.

Comment: Your question and answer by scmartin helped me a lot on understanding the equation, so I also wanted to contribute to this question as well. ;)

Comment: I'm very glad you have done that :-)

Answer (score 4):

This comes from an approximation of the logarithms. The variance can be written by rearranging the logarithms as $$\left( \ln\left[ \frac{\frac{1}{n_0}\sum_{i=1}^{n_0}f(q_i)e^{-\beta U_1(q_i)}}{\langle f(q)e^{-\beta U_1(q)}\rangle_0} \right] - \ln\left[ \frac{\frac{1}{n_1}\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}f(q_i)e^{-\beta U_0(q_i)}}{\langle f(q)e^{-\beta U_0(q)}\rangle_1} \right] \right)^2$$

For large enough sample sizes the argument of each logarithm approaches 1, and the logarithm can be approximated as $\ln x \approx x-1$.

You then can expand the square and approximate the sums with the ensemble averages, though for me it is more clear to leave in the explicit sums, unlike Bennett's derivation. Gavin Crooks' thesis is helpful in following this derivation.